# SOLR INDEX using JAVA API

Tags: java, api, solr, indexing

Can some one help me with this question, I know Solr can be indexed using XML, JSON, etc thru the HTTP API. But is there anyway to index and/or query Solr in java api call, not thru the web.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `solrj` as java API.  See https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj